# Run a script in an existing Terminal window when the current line already contains some text

Tags: applescript

If the current line in the frontmost Terminal tab contained the text `aa`, this would run the command `aauptime`:

```
set cmd to "uptime"
tell application "Terminal"
    try
        do script cmd in window 1
    on error
        do script cmd
    end try
    activate
end tell
```

You could obviously add something like `tell app "System Events" to keystroke "ku" using control down` before `do script`, but does anyone know any better solutions?

Comment: A workaround : Run this before your command to clear the prompt : `do script "" in window 1`

Comment: @KassymDorsel That would run `aa` in my example scenario.

Comment: It would, but the prompt would then be clear for running your next command.

Comment: Similar to your keystroke "ku", you could simulate a Control-C.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can call a shell script without targeting the terminal, right?

Comment: Yeah I do know about `do shell script`. `uptime` was a bad example here.